# Circle on canvas has rough edges

Tags: android, draw, geometry

I want a circle on the canvas in android app.

It can be done either using a bitmap of circle or actually drawing a circle.

I have done both but the circle in later has rough edges.

Why is this happening. And how can i get the Circle as i expect ?

**edit:**
Since android is running on phones varying in pixel density and screen size, is there a recommended method ? I want the circle to be smooth all the time.

Comment: do you want to set image in circular shape?

Comment: i dont understand what u mean

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
paint.setAntiAlias(true)
```

or set a flag during creation

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
```

And tell us if it works

Comment: I will try this. Could you plz explain what this does exactly ?

Comment: This flag forces all the drawing methods that support antialiasing to use it. Antialiasing is basically a bunch of techniques to enhance the rendering quality. It will of course use more resources. More on antialiasing:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing

Comment: so is it better to use bitmap instead of drawing circle ?

Comment: No, the best solution is to use antialiased shader (Paint with antialias)